# Vector Plotting in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

I am trying to execute ploting program based on c on a ubuntu machine but it is showing error. I have attached my code and output below thank you

Here's my code of c language for vector ploting
Plotingvector.c

```
 #include <apop.h>

 void plot_matrix_now(gsl_matrix *data)
 {
     static FILE *gp = NULL;
     if (!gp)
         gp = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
     if (!gp)
     {
         printf("Couldn't open Gnuplot.\n");
         return;
     }

     fprintf(gp,"reset; plot '-' \n");
     apop_matrix_print(data, .output_pipe=gp);
     fflush(gp);
 }

 int main()
 {
     apop_db_open("data-climate.db");
     plot_matrix_now(apop_query_to_matrix("select (year*12+month)/12., temp from temp"));
 }
```

Here are the command to compile the program:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 Plotingvector.c -o Plotingvector.out -lapophenia -lgsl -lsqlite3
```

ERRORS:-

```
/tmp/ccs0P974.o: In function `main': Plotingvector.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `apop_query_to_matrix'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What is `apop_query_to_matrix`, answer this and your issue will be gone.  Does `#include<apop.h>` have any references of `apop_query_to_matrix`?

Comment: Yes #include<apop.h> has reference to apop_query_to_matrix.

Comment: According to http://apophenia.info/group__all__public.html `apop_query_to_matrix` does not exist.

Comment: So what's the solution for this? Ty